# Breaking up minified html

Tags: indentation

Is it possible to do this with vanilla emacs? If not what changes do I need to make.

Original test.html

```
<a id="try_redacted" target="_blank" href="http://redacted.com/game/2d/?try=1" style="right: -0.5em; bottom: 6em;"><img src="assets/img/try_redacted.png" alt="Try redacted" border="0" width="100%"></a>
```

End Result example.html

```
<a id="try_redacted" target="_blank" href="http://redacted.com/game/2d/?try=1" style="right: -0.5em; bottom: 6em;">
  <img src="assets/img/try_redacted.png" alt="Try redacted" border="0" width="100%">
</a>
```

M-x html-mode
and M-x indent-region
didn't seem to help.

Comment: I usually do a query-replace `><` to `>^J<` to insert newlines between tags. Then select the whole buffer and `indent-region`.

Comment: Try to keep in mind that whitespace in HTML is significant - so, by formatting it to have a different structure, you may be changing how the document is presented.

Comment: Please ask an explicit question. "is it possible to do this" with an unexplained example is not easy to understand, and not useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The function `te/maybe-expand-tag` does that. The `tagedit` library advises [`fill-paragraph`](https://github.com/magnars/tagedit/blob/b3a70101a0dcf85498c92b7fcfa7fdbac869746c/tagedit.el#L969) with it.

If you want to try install and activate `tagedit-mode` which is available on [marmelade](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/tagedit) and [melpa](https://melpa.org/#/tagedit).

Afterwards you can just use `fill-paragraph` to get the tag-wise fill behavior.
The function `fill-paragraph` is bound to the key sequence <kbd>M-q</kbd>.